# laravel query to make pagination

Tags: laravel, pagination

```
$users =  SELECT users.id, 
                 users.name, 
                 cd.title, 
                 cd.updated_at, 
                 profiles.avatar 
          FROM   `users` 
                 JOIN (SELECT Max(id) max_id, 
                              user_id 
                       FROM   book 
                       GROUP  BY user_id) c_max 
                   ON ( c_max.user_id = users.id ) 
                 JOIN book cd 
                   ON ( cd.id = c_max.user_id ) 
                 JOIN profiles 
                   ON ( profiles.user_id = users.id ) 
          ORDER  BY cd.updated_at DESC
```

i am using this to get data in laravel query

$users =  DB::select(DB::raw('SELECT users.id, users.name, cd.title, cd.updated_at, profiles.avatar FROM `users` JOIN ( SELECT MAX(id) max_id, user_id FROM book GROUP BY user_id )
 c_max ON (c_max.user_id = users.id) JOIN book cd ON (cd.id = c_max.user_id) JOIN profiles ON (profiles.user_id = users.id) ORDER by cd.updated_at DESC limit 24 offset 0'));

Comment: how can i make pagination in this laravel query Please help!!!!

Comment: please mention all your models, relationships and what you tried?

Comment: there are 3 tables. 1st users in that data of users, 2nd table is book which have book name and user_id and 3rd one is profiles in that have User Profile pic means avatar. i have to display users list by 'Most Active' which i get by this query

Comment: but problem is that using DB::raw so i cant able to use laravel paginate query